# Running Node Express server bringing up error message

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, webpack

New to webpack, trying to run my own server (`node server.js`), but I get this message:

```
$ node server.js
/path/to/server.js:3
import path from 'path'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

**My server.js:**

```
require("babel-register");

import path from 'path'
import Express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import counterApp from './reducers'
import App from './containers/App'

import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

const app = Express()
const port = 3000

// This is fired every time a request is made
app.use(handleRender)


function handleRender(req, res) {
   // Create a new Redux store instance
   const store = createStore(counterApp) // this is taken from './reducers'

   // Render the component to a string
   const html = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}> // Needs an import?
         <App /> // this is defined in './containers/...'
      </Provider>
   )

   // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
   const preloadedState = store.getState()

   // Send the rendered page back to the client
   res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}

// Yet to be defined...
function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
   return
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Paulos3000 Redux Universal Example</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <div id='root'>${html}</div>
            <script>
               window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
            </script>
            <script src='/static/bundle.js'></script>
         </body>
      </html>
}

app.listen(port)
```

Can anyone see a problem with my code? Let me know if you need me to include any more info (not sure exactly what to include as I don't know the source of the problem).

UPDATE:

```
SyntaxError: /path/to/server.js: Unexpected token (25:6)
  23 |   
  24 |    const html = renderToString(
> 25 |       <Provider>
     |       ^
  26 |          <App />
  27 |       </Provider>
  28 |    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Node version, it doesn't support the `import` syntax.

Try using imports via `require()` instead:

```
const path = require('path').default
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I know how to change `import path from 'path'` to `const path = require('path')`, but how would I change this to ES5 syntax: `import { createStore } from 'redux'`?

Comment: `const createStore = require('redux').createStore` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

`babel-register` doesn't apply to the file you use it in, only to files that you subsequently `require()`.

For instance:

```
// bootstrap.js
require("babel-register");
require("./server");

// server.js
import path from 'path'
import Express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
...
```

And start the server with:

```
$ node bootstrap.js
```

This does assume that you already have a valid Babel setup. If you don't, create a file named `.babelrc` in the same directory as `server.js`, containing the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

And also install the preset modules:

```
$ npm i babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Comment: Maybe I don't have valid Babel setup. When I do this I get error: (see update...)

Comment: @Paulos3000 it looks like you are (at least) missing the `react` preset for Babel. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react

Comment: Already had that installed actually, and also referenced in my webpack.config.js ...

Comment: @Paulos3000 you're running `server.js` directly, so Webpack doesn't come into play. You need to create a standalone Babel setup as well (I've edited my answer to show how).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `.babelrc`. That's partly fixed it... It's now tripping up on the html return part of my server.js... I tried including `"plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]` but no joy. Sorry - this is all a bit new to me, there seems to be an endless list of plugins/presets needed!

Comment: @Paulos3000 JSX _looks_ like HTML, [but it isn't entirely the same](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/jsx). Try removing the `<!doctype...>` declaration.